# Membership.CreateUser keeps throwing 'InvalidAnswer'

Tags: asp.net, membership-provider

I've been trying to use the `CreateUser` method to add users to my database. One thing I want is that password questions and answers aren't required, and so I have this in my `Web.config`:

```
    membership>
                <providers>
                    <clear/>
                    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="CBCFXConnString" 
enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
enablePasswordReset="true" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="8" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
applicationName="CBCFX"/>
```

as you can see, I've set the `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` to `false`. This setting has been in my configuration ever since I started programming, and I am just dumbfounded as to why that `InvalidAnswer` persists when I try adding a user with this line:

```
fxSMP.CreateUser(userName, passWord, eMail, null, null, true, null, out status);
```

I've even tried passing empty strings to the question and answer arguments:

```
string pwQuestion = "";
string pwAnswer = "";

fxSMP.CreateUser(userName, passWord, eMail, pwQuestion, pwAnswer, true, null, out status);
```

but still nothing. What can I do to make this work?

EDIT: I've gone around the internet some more, and there appears to be an overload method wherein you could only input a UserName, Password and Email. Why does this overload not seem to be available in my instance of `SqlMembershipProvider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question I can't see how you are declaring the `membership` element in the `web.config` file but make sure you set the `defaultProvider` attribute...just in case. Also, I'd suggest you to use a different overload of the `CreateUser` method...

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(string username, string password, string email)
```

### Edit

Now, since you are using the `SqlMembershipProvider` this overload will not be available. Why? First, because you are NOT supposed to be calling this method directly on your client code. You should rather use the `Membership` class. If you set the `defaultProvider` of the `membership` element in the `web.config` file and set the `requiresQuestionAndAnswer` to `false` then you shouldn't have any issues whatsoever.

By the way, check out this [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.createuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I've ended up using one of the overloads. Problem is, that overload isn't available in my instance of the `MembershipProvider`, so I've made an explicit call instead.

Comment: Your question starts to make more sense now. I'll append an edit to my answer

Comment: interesting. I've just set the `defaultProvider` in my `Web.config` along with the `requiresQuestionAndAnswer=false`, it works okay now. BTW, I've been in that link you posted dozens of times in the past few days LOL